# Kubectl proxy behind NGINX: invalid upgrade response

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, proxy, kubectl, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to add a local Kubernates cluster to my GitLab group for CI/CD deployments. I've started with running the following command:

`kubectl proxy --address 0.0.0.0 --accept-hosts '.*'`

I've tested it executing `curl http://localhost:8001/api` and running `curl http://192.168.1.2:8001/api` from another machine in the same network. Proxy was available in my local network.

The next step was to make the proxy available on the internet behind `kubernates.example.com`. For that I've configured NGINX as the following:

```
server {
    server_name kubernates.example.com;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 80;

    include ssl_standart_conf;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:8001/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

Executing `curl https://kubernates.example.com/api` returned the following error:

```
invalid upgrade response: status code 200
```

Kubernates proxy logs

```
E0225 22:33:50.944018 1642369 upgradeaware.go:312] Proxy upgrade error: invalid upgrade response: status code 200
E0225 22:33:50.944060 1642369 proxy_server.go:144] Error while proxying request: invalid upgrade response: status code 200
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I've managed to resolve the issue. The following nginx configuration made a trick

```
server {
    server_name kubernates.example.com;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 80;

    include ssl_standart_conf;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:8001/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since websocket protocol is used by kubectl for at least port-forwarding and interactive shell, it's better to make it work when client wants to upgrade connection, rather than effectively disabling websocket by using http/1.0 (default for `proxy_pass` without explicit `proxy_http_version 1.1`).

The problem with widespread copypaste solution for nginx/websocket is that `Connection: upgrade` header is always sent to upstream even if client hasn't requested protocol upgrading.

This seems to confuse kube-api-server when it sends requests with 'Connection: Upgrade' to internal services like metrics server and gets HTTP 200 instead of HTTP 101 response.

This is how to make websocket to work for kubernetes api proxy location in nginx only when requested. It solves `invalid upgrade response: status code 200` and avoids breaking port-forward and other useful features that rely on websocket.

```
# Note: map directive should be declared in http, but not server context
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    # $connection_upgrade will have value "upgrade" only if $http_upgrade is not empty
    default "upgrade";
    ""      "";
}
...
server {
...
    location / {
        ...
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        ...
        proxy_pass https://kubernetes_api;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this information. It was invaluable in assisting me to diagnose why my managed AKS cluster wasn't able to correctly make requests of my Rancher instance. In my case, I was able to simply exclude the proxy_set_header Connection Upgrade header from my Nginx ingress controller and retain only Upgrade websocket.